# Google Tensor CPU clock speed throttled when there's still thermal headroom remain

Tags: android, performance, optimization, performance-testing, cpu

Kind of a specific question. Hoping something can provide some insights.

### Background

So for background context, from the online source, it seems like Google Tensor SoC has 8 cores:

- 2 large cores  @ 2.80 GHz
- 2 medium cores @ 2.25 GHz
- 4 small cores  @ 1.80 GHz

### Problem

I have a CPU-bound workload, that performs real time video analysis using the frames coming from the camera feed in a background thread.

My workload performs reasonably well in older devices that runs older SoC (e.g. Snapdragon 855). However, I noticed that the performance on the Google Tensor SoC is about twice as slow as the older SoC. (E.g. the latency to process a frame is now 400ms vs 200ms on the older chip).

### Observation

I used the following commend in `adb shell` to observe the CPU frequency during my workload:

```
watch -n 1 cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
```

And I observed the following output on Tensor SoC.

```
Every 1.0s: cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq /sys/device*Tue Jul 11 22:45:19 2023

1803000
1803000
1803000
1803000
2253000 # <- Medium Core
2253000 # <- Medium Core
1826000 # <- Big Core (Core #6)
1826000 # <- Big Core (Core #7)
```

It seems like the "big cores" (core 6 and core 7) are running at throttled speed @ 1.80 GHz instead of the maximum clock speed.

I also used the `PowerManager.getCurrentThermalStatus()` to check the current thermal throttling status, to see if the CPU is throttled due to thermal reasons, and I observed that it was returning `THERMAL_STATUS_NONE`.

From the Android Studio System Profiler, it seems like my workload (coloured bright green) is indeed running on one of the big cores (core 7) in this case, and the CPU clock speed was indeed capped at 1.8 GHz.

[image: Android Profiler Screenshot]

While looking at the clock speed on the older SoC, it seems like the CPU was able to sustain its maximum speed for the entire workload:

```
1785600
1785600
1785600
1785600
2419200 # <- Medium Core
2419200 # <- Medium Core
2419200 # <- Medium Core
2841600 # <- Big Core
```

### Question

Based on the observation, it seems like the CPU is throttled down for reasons unrelated to thermal limitation.

Are there factors other than thermal that can cause the CPU to throttle down? If yes, how do I narrow down the potential culprit?

Comment: Just making sure you are aware of/using [PerformanceHintManager](https://developer.android.com/games/optimize/adpf#hint-api)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, just tried it on my Pixel 6 Pro. The `createHintSession` method returned `null`. Based on the docs, seems like the pixel devices doesn't support performance hint :'(